# Cakephp migration 1.3 to 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a project in **cakephp 1.3**. is it possible to migrate it in **cakephp 3.0** and i am beginner  in **cakephp**. any good suggestion?

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-x-migration-guide.html

Comment: Note that the migration tools do only a small part of the work for you. I don't think I'd recommend a migration of this type for someone new to Cake, unless it's a very small project.

Comment: @GregSchmidt - I am in a similar problem and there is a significant change in Models from 1.3 to 3.6. Would the migration tools help me here? The project I am working on is quite small.

Comment: The migration tools were definitely helpful in getting things reorganized, adding namespace definitions, those sorts of things. And the new ORM has been built to optionally accept arguments similar to how the old `find` function worked (as a parameterized array) if you don't want to convert to the new "chained" methods right away. And the entities returned will emulate the old arrays (though the nesting of retrieved data is different). In other words, if you don't mind your code having a 1.3 feel to it, the changes for a project of just a couple models wouldn't be so overwhelming.

Comment: But validation is all different, there are subtle differences in casing and pluralization of things that the migration tools didn't handle for me (they may have improved in the meantime; this was a couple years ago), saving and deleting data requires working with entities, and if you want to fully embrace the new ORM you'll need to change the structure of every single `find` and `get`.

Comment: Long story short, if you're converting a project, by all means use the migration tools. Just be aware that they are only the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: I think we can not directly update it from 1.3 to 3.6. First we have to update it on 2 and than we should  update it in another higher . I means step by step.